# I need the name or number of the bricks that the minifigures are on

Tags: part-identification

[image]

I need the name of grey pieces that the minifigures are standing on.

Answer (score 19):

It's not a very clear picture, but I suspect it's not a single part, but rather made from the following 3 parts (stacked on top of each other in top to bottom order) :

- 1x [Light Bluish Gray Slope, Curved 2 x 2 x 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15068#T=C&C=86)

[image]

- 1x [Light Bluish Gray Plate, Modified 2 x 2 x 2/3 with 2 Studs on Side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99206#T=C&C=86)

[image]

- 1x [Light Bluish Gray Brick 2 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3003#T=C&C=86)

[image]

And attached onto a base plate, resulting in (color added to show the separate parts) :

[image]